# Array of StringBuilders not working with P/Invoke

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling

This was marked as a duplicate of [Pass writeable StringBuilder array to C++ from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24828391/pass-writeable-stringbuilder-array-to-c-from-c-sharp) but that does not at all address the issue of the use of `StringBuilder[]` and only comments on the incorrect use of `wcsncpy` and `MarshalAs`. I am not even using `wcsncpy` or `MarshalAs` anywhere in my question.

---

So, I'm trying to use one of my C++ functions in C# like this:

```
[DllImport("CPPDLLImport", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern void StringBuilderArrayTest(StringBuilder[] text, int[] textLengths, int numberOfTextItems);
```

Now, normally this would work fine of course, but I'm don't think I'm getting the correct data in C++ from `text`.

So, in order to test this I set up a P/Invoke project.

I am calling the method in C# using this:

```
var stringBuilderArray = new StringBuilder[]
{
    new StringBuilder("abc"),
    new StringBuilder("def"),
    new StringBuilder("ghi")
};
var stringBuilderLengths = new int[3] { 3, 3, 3 };
StringBuilderArrayTest(stringBuilderArray, stringBuilderLengths, 3);
```

And this is my method in C++ - to test it I'm just printing it to the screen, and to make sure it definitely wasn't `printf`, I am literally printing it character-by-character just to be sure:

```
EXPORT void StringBuilderArrayTest(wchar_t** text, int* textLengths, int numberOfTextItems) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTextItems; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < textLengths[i]; j++)
    printf("%c", text[i][j]);
}
```

And, well, the parameter `text` is definitely not right. It's just giving me "ÇPÿ" three times - definitely not the string "abc", "def" or "ghi".

Is it just not marshaling the `StringBuilder` array correctly? If so, how can I get this array of strings across?

---

UPDATE:
OK, I have decided to use a `string[]` for sending data to my C++ code, however, I now need to do the reverse - sending data *from* C++ into C#. So, what alternatives are there to using an array of `StringBuilder`?

Comment: `wchar_t**`  Double stars in C++ are hard-enough to deal with in C++ code itself.  It's not surprising things are not working for a language that isn't C++.  Maybe there is a way to do this, but if it were me, I would just send a single string, maybe `abc;def;ghi`, and deal with that by parsing out the `;`.

Comment: Why StringBuilder instead of string[]?

Comment: I was doing that because I have lots of character arrays, and I know that creating lots of strings in C# can be a bit costly. But, I can use a "string" array for now as I suppose it won't be *that bad*... But, if anyone *does know* how I could make it work with StringBuilders, then that would be preferred.

Comment: A `StringBuilder` is less costly than concatenation when creating a string from other strings.But I don't see that happening in the code. If you're instantiating a string from a character array, you can do `var myString = new string(someCharArray);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass writeable StringBuilder array to C++ from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24828391/pass-writeable-stringbuilder-array-to-c-from-c-sharp) and also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928094/passing-c-sharp-string-array-to-c-dll-and-modify-it-there

Comment: You don't need a `StringBuilder` unless you plan to modify the string on the C++ side and use the modified value back in C#. And there is no marshalling for `StringBuilder[]`, so you can only do one at a time.

Comment: Since you are passing text to the C++ code StringBuilder[] is the wrong type. Use string[], as @jdweng says.

Comment: I'm 95.436% sure you found a bug in the marshaler.  It does make an attempt to convert the StringBuilders but what it produces is hard to make sense of.  Each one turns into a pointer+pointer+0+0+0, sort of resembles a System.Object but the pointer values make little sense.  In this specific case you have no reason to avoid string[] since you are not writing anything back.  If you would you'd have to worry a heckofalot more about their Capacity property.  So easy, peasy, use string[] instead, that works just fine.